# Proof Regarding Property of Odd Integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

The question I am working on is:

> "Use a direct proof to show that every odd integer is the difference of two squares."

Proof:

Let n be an odd integer: $n = 2k + 1$, where $k \in Z$

Let the difference of two different squares be, $a^2-b^2$, where $a,b \in Z$.

Hence, $n=2k+1=a^2-b^2$...

As you can see, this a dead-end. Appealing to the answer key, I found that they let the difference of two different squares be, $(k+1)^2-k^2$. I understand their use of $k$--$k$ is one number, and $k+1$ is a different number--;however, why did they choose to add $1$? Why couldn't we have added $2$?

Comment: Adding the 1 is the correct way to start... try it out.  Simplify (k+1)^2-k^2 and see if you get something familiar.

Comment: @kaine No, I understand that is very helpful to use 1, but why couldn't we have chosen 2?

Comment: if you use 2 it becomes 4k+4 which is not an odd number; if you use one (k+1)^2-k^2 = 2k+1. You can extract something interesting from the 2 but it won't be the odd number proof you are looking for.

Comment: "why did they choose to add 1?" Because it was something simple to try. And when they tried it, it worked!

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate – I think the questioner is misunderstanding what they are being asked, rather than failing to find an answer. See my answer, which would be completely inappropriate for the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on here, I think, is you're confused about what you're being asked to prove.

The statement is "every odd integer is the difference of two squares", or, more precisely, 
 "**for all** odd integers $n$, **there exist** $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 - b^2 = n$". Think for a bit about what the difference between "for all..." and "there exists..." is, and maybe you'll realise what's going on.

You have to come up with a proof that works for every odd integer, so you start with an arbitrary choice $n = 2k + 1$. But then you seem to go on to pick an arbitrary difference of two squares, $a^2 - b^2$. But that's not necessary – we're not trying to prove anything about *every* difference of two squares, just *one*, so you only need to show that there *is* a difference of two squares that satisfies the condition, and in particular *you* choose it, it isn't arbitrary.

Think of the statement as "if you give me an odd integer $n$, I can give you $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2 - b^2 = n$". In particular, you can give me whatever odd integer you like, but then *I* get to choose what $a$ and $b$ are. In particular, I can choose $a$ to be $b + 1$ if I like.

From one of your comments:

> We have to show that $a^2 - b^2$ is an odd number

But in general that's just not true. For example, $4^2 - 2^2 = 12$. So if you've found yourself trying to prove that statement, you've clearly gone wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach, a graphical proof:
$$\underbrace{\begin{array}{ccccc}
1\odot & 3\otimes & 5\odot & \cdots & (2k - 1)\otimes\\\hline
\bigodot & \bigotimes & \bigodot & \cdots & \bigotimes\\
\bigotimes & \bigotimes & \bigodot & \cdots & \bigotimes\\
\bigodot & \bigodot & \bigodot & \cdots & \bigotimes\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\[1ex]
\bigotimes & \bigotimes & \bigotimes & \cdots & \bigotimes\\
\end{array}}_{\textstyle k}$$

From this we have $k^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 + \dotsb + (2k - 1)$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}
2k + 1 &= \Big(1 + 3 + 5 + \dotsb + (2k - 1) + (2k + 1)\Big) - \Big(1 + 3 + 5 + \dotsb + (2k - 1)\Big)\\
       &= (k + 1)^2 - k^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1: Re-purposing the picture-proof for "The sum of consecutive odd integers, starting at 1, is a square." Nice!

Comment: I believe a proof of this sort is a little beyond my abilities, at this point in time.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain how the $(k + 1)^2 - k^2$ thing arises from this. Does that help?

Comment: A classic, from Fibonacci's [The Book of Squares (Liber Quadratorum)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Squares)

Answer (score 6):

Directly:

$$2k+1=k^2+2k+1-k^2=(k+1)^2-k^2\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Here you have another approach...

Note that
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n
  {
    i
  }
=
  \frac{n(n+1)}2
$$
so that the sum of the first $n$ odd naturals is
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n
  {
    (2i-1)
  }
=
  2\left(
    \sum_{i=1}^n
    {
      i
    }
  \right)
- n
=
  n(n+1)-n
=
  n^2
$$
We have showed that the sum of the first $n$ odd naturals is $n^2$. The $n$-th odd natural is, trivially, equal to the sum of the first $n$ minus the sum of the first $n-1$:
$$
  2n-1
=
  \sum_{i=1}^n
  {
    (2i-1)
  }
  -
  \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}
  {
    (2i-1)
  }
$$
and from what we found, we can write it as
$$
2n-1 = n^2 - (n-1)^2
$$

Comment: A classic, from Fibonacci's [The Book of Squares (Liber Quadratorum)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Squares)

Comment: @MathGems Wow, didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a^2 - b^2 = (a + b)(a - b)$. Solve the simultaneous equations $a + b = n$ and $a - b = 1$.

This is where you got $(k + 1)^2 - k^2$ from - $(a + b)(a - b)$ then matches to $((k + 1) + k)((k + 1) - k)$.

Comment: What are you setting $a^2 - b^2$ to get the simultaneous equations $a+b=n$ and $a-b=1$?

Comment: I notice that I have a lot of freedom in choosing what $(a + b)$ and $(a - b)$ will be, so I purposely give them nice values to ensure that the product will give $n$ while $a$ and $b$ are positive. The obvious way to do it is to let the larger one $a + b = n$ and the smaller one $a - b = 1$.

Comment: How is it that you have freedom in that choice? We have to show that $a^2-b^2$ is an odd number; so, we assume that that is true. Since $n$ is some arbitrary odd number ($n=2k+1$), then we set $a^2-b^2$ to equal to $n$: $a^2-b^2 = 2k+1$

Comment: Sure you could do that, but my approach is also valid because $a$ and $b$ are two variables so it's fine to restrict them with two equations. In fact, the $(k + 1)^2 - k^2$ thing probably *came from* observing the results of solving $a + b = n$ and $a - b = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2k + 1 = 1 \times (2k  +1) = (\color{#C00}{k + 1} -{\bf k}) (\color{#C00}{k + 1} +\bf{ k})$$